# Weiner Filter - why does this computation explain that the necessary filter is a weiner filter?

Tags: filters, power-spectral-density, random-process, stationary

[image]

$X_1(t), X_2(t)$ are random WSS processes with expectation 0, and correlation functions $R_{X_1}(\tau), R_{X_2}(\tau), R_{X_1,X_2}(\tau)$ 
 $n(t)$ is a  white noise with SPD $S_n(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}$ independent from $X_1(t),X_2(t)$. 
 $h_1(\tau),h_2(\tau)$ are the impulse response functions of the systems in the schematic, and they are LTI.

 In the question i’m asked to find the optimal linear filter to approximate $Y_1(t)$ from $\{Z(t)\}$ (which i’m doing after i’ve proven that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are wide sense stationary.

The solution starts by defining $$W_t := Y_2(t) +n(t)$$so now $$Z(t) = Y_1(t)+W(t)$$where the solution alleges that $W(t)$ is a WSS random process, and then proves it’s also joint WSS with $Y_1$, then it uses said computation to say that therefore the optimal linear filter is a Weiner filter.
[image]

**my questions:** 
why is $W(t)$ WSS? 
why does showing that $W(t)$ is Joint WSS with $Y_1(t)$ proves that the optimal filter is a Weiner filter?